# grep - pattern as variable

Tags: regex

file name: Data.txt

Inside this file:

```
...
3754  Skype Helper    
375  Skype Helper    
37  Skype
...
```

file name: shell.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

IFS='
'
var="Skype"

grep "\d\+\s\+${var}$" /Users/run/Documents/Data.txt >> /Users/run/Documents/output.txt
```

The output should be:

```
37  Skype
```

but

I get:

```
3754  Skype Helper    
375  Skype Helper    
37  Skype
```

Thanks a lot

Comment: what about `^\d{2}\s+Skype` ?

Comment: whey you want `37  Skype` as output? becouse of the two digits?

Comment: Try `grep "[0-9]\+[ \t]*\+${var}$"`

Comment: After the word Skype no character should stay there

Comment: I only get `37 Skype`, see **[my answer with a code demo link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52265248/3832970)**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using a BRE POSIX pattern that does not support PCRE (Perl-like) `\d` and `\s`, you may replace `\d` with `[0-9]` bracket expression and `\s` with `[[:space:]]` POSIX character class:

```
grep "[0-9]\+[[:space:]]\+${var}\$"
```

Note you may escape the last `$` to make it an explicit literal dollar symbol, but it is not necessary as the trailing dollar is correctly parsed as the end of string symbol, and this will work, too:

```
grep "[0-9]\+[[:space:]]\+${var}$"
```

If you do not want to overescape, you may make the pattern POSIX ERE compatible:

```
grep -E "[0-9]+[[:space:]]+${var}$"
     ^^
```

You may actually keep on using `\d` and `\s` if you tell `grep` to use a PCRE regex engine to parse the pattern:

```
grep -P "\d+\s+${var}$"
     ^^
```

**See the [online demo](https://ideone.com/x3kOhE)**.

Comment: i have tried to get the output from @Wiktor Stribiżew "(see online Demo )" but i can´t reproduce it on my Macbook yet.

I have figured out that the version of grep on the online Demo was 2.27. I have installed grep from Homebrew and the version is 3.1( Before (grep (BSD grep) 2.5.1-FreeBSD)I However the output is the wrong one because I don´t get anything by the output. Somebody could tell me what's going on here? Thanks

Comment: You do not need to use the PCRE version. Use the simpler one.

Comment: it doesn't work. Is it possible that another thing is not working properly? I have tested the command grep with other online code provider like you and it works fine

Comment: I guess that is related to `\+`. Try `grep "[0-9][0-9]*[[:space:]][[:space:]]*${var}\$"`, or `grep "[0-9]\{1,\}[[:space:]]\{1,\}${var}\$"`

Comment: I've found the reason why it didn´t work. The Data.txt file was corrupted.

Comment: @sarcon Glad you finally found out the problem.

Answer (score 0):

i work on a mac (macOS high sierra) and i **CAN'T** get the output I am looking for. I would appreciate so much if somebody try the first both files on my first posting but with the pattern from @Wiktor Stribiżew: